# How to get the displayname of a CIFilter?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to get a list of the display names of the CIFilters. Have found [this site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Filter_Attribute_Keys) which has the constants that should give the name (with other info), but the code below is not working.

Console output:

```
here 01
here 02
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CIAccordionFoldTransition 0x7a672dc0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key CIAttributeFilterName.'
```

My code:

```
func getCIFilterName(filterName: String) -> String{
    var res = "abc"

    let fltr = CIFilter(name:filterName)
    println("here 01")
    if contains(fltr.attributes().keys, kCIAttributeFilterDisplayName){
        println("here 02")
        res = fltr.valueForKey(kCIAttributeFilterDisplayName) as String
    }
    println("here 03")

    return res
}
```

Comment: Please show your real code. What you have shown would not compile. _Copy and paste_ your actual code into Stack Overflow. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't post the orginal, cause it is really messy, mapping over an array and stuff.

Comment: That's cool, but the proper technique is then to rewrite to a simplified version, test that, and paste it into Stack Overflow. Posting fake code is wrong, and your code was fake - it wouldn't compile to start with. That means I couldn't just paste it into an app and try it. So you are putting obstacles in the way of someone who you are asking to help you.

Comment: BTW I'm glad you mentioned mapping because I was going to suggest that. :)

Comment: You are right. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `attributes` method returns a dictionary. So much simpler to do it like this:

```
func getCIFilterName(filterName: String) -> String {
    var res = "abc"
    let fltr = CIFilter(name:filterName)
    if let disp = fltr.attributes()[kCIAttributeFilterDisplayName] as? String {
        res = disp
    }
    return res
}
```

But I do not like your trick of returning a false value `"abc"` if we fail. This is what Optionals are for - to get us away from "magic values" of this sort. So rewrite like this:

```
func getCIFilterName(filterName: String) -> String! {
    var res : String! = nil
    let fltr = CIFilter(name:filterName)
    if let disp = fltr.attributes()[kCIAttributeFilterDisplayName] as? String {
        res = disp
    }
    return res
}
```

Do not forget, however, to check the returned value against nil, or you'll crash if you try to use it for anything (if it *is* nil).